# how to run cuda-uninstaller without interaction?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

the cuda-unintaller does not have any help message. I try to use `-s` or `--silent` but it does not work. I do not want to run the uninstaller on all machines manually and select the components to uninstall one by one. How can I do it?

Comment: To clarify, we're trying to uninstall using the existing `/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin/cuda-unintaller` binary.